How would one create a layer list drawable in Jetpack Compose?
layer list drawable image
The above was drawn using layer-list.
<layer-list>
    <item
        android:width="100dp"
        android:height="30dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="1px"
                android:color="#00000000" />

            <solid android:color="#00000000" />

        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:width="2dp"
        android:bottom="1dp"
        android:top="20dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/tdTeal" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:width="2dp"
        android:bottom="20dp"
        android:top="0dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/tdTeal" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:width="2dp"
        android:bottom="0dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:top="20dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/tdTeal" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:width="2dp"
        android:bottom="20dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:top="0dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/tdTeal" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:height="2dp"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="90dp"
        android:top="-1dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/tdTeal" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:height="2dp"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:left="90dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:top="-1dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/tdTeal" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:height="2dp"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="90dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/tdTeal" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:height="2dp"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:left="90dp"
        android:right="0dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/tdTeal" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>

In the past, we could set buttons to have a custom background such as the above and have text or Icons within the rectangle. How would one recreate the above in Jetpack Compose? Ultimately I want the below button. Any help would be appreciated.
Goal
If the above is too complicated, can we use both Compose and drawable together? I've tried the following
Box(
    modifier = modifier.size(250.dp).paint(
        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.border_box)
    )
)

But Android Studio is spitting out rendering issues.

Drawing this kind of background from a drawable could lead to aspect ratio issues. It's probably better to use one of the drawing modifiers like drawBehind to have access to the current size of the composable.
// Encapsulate all of the line parameters like width and color into this function
fun DrawScope.borderBoxCorner(points: List<Offset>) =
    drawPoints(points, PointMode.Polygon, Color.Green, 8f, StrokeCap.Square)

TextButton(
    onClick = {},
    modifier = Modifier
        .drawBehind {
            val w = size.width
            val h = size.height
            val smallerSide = min(w, h)
            // These 2 values determine relative size of the corners
            val padding = smallerSide * 0.1f
            val edge = smallerSide * 0.35f
            val topLeft = Offset(padding, padding)
            borderBoxCorner(
                listOf(topLeft.copy(y = edge), topLeft, topLeft.copy(x = edge))
            )
            val botRight = Offset(w - padding, h - padding)
            borderBoxCorner(
                listOf(botRight.copy(y = h - edge), botRight, botRight.copy(x = w - edge))
            )
        }
) {
    Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.ShoppingCart, contentDescription = null)
    Text("Capture")
}




Try this Its work according to your requirements
CaptureButton()
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .background(Color.Black)
        .padding(16.dp)
        .height(100.dp),
    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
) {
    // Corner Borders
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .matchParentSize()
            .padding(4.dp)
    ) {
        CornerBorders()
    }

    // Camera Icon and Text
    Row(verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
        val cameraPainter: Painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_order) // Replace with your drawable resource
        Image(
            painter = cameraPainter,
            contentDescription = "Camera Icon",
            modifier = Modifier.size(40.dp)
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp))
        Text(
            text = "Capture",
            color = Color.White,
            fontSize = 24.sp,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
        )
    }
}

CornerBorders()
Canvas(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
    val strokeWidth = 4.dp.toPx()
    val length = 20.dp.toPx()
    val color = Color(0xFF7BB972)

    // Top left
    drawRect(
        color = color,
        topLeft = Offset(0f, 0f),
        size = Size(strokeWidth, length)
    )
    drawRect(
        color = color,
        topLeft = Offset(0f, 0f),
        size = Size(length, strokeWidth)
    )

    // Top right
    drawRect(
        color = color,
        topLeft = Offset(size.width - strokeWidth, 0f),
        size = Size(strokeWidth, length)
    )
    drawRect(
        color = color,
        topLeft = Offset(size.width - length, 0f),
        size = Size(length, strokeWidth)
    )

    // Bottom left
    drawRect(
        color = color,
        topLeft = Offset(0f, size.height - length),
        size = Size(strokeWidth, length)
    )
    drawRect(
        color = color,
        topLeft = Offset(0f, size.height - strokeWidth),
        size = Size(length, strokeWidth)
    )

    // Bottom right
    drawRect(
        color = color,
        topLeft = Offset(size.width - strokeWidth, size.height - length),
        size = Size(strokeWidth, length)
    )
    drawRect(
        color = color,
        topLeft = Offset(size.width - length, size.height - strokeWidth),
        size = Size(length, strokeWidth)
    )
}


